# Getting notification from PayPal on new subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

While playing in sandbox and setting up recurring payments via SetExpressCheckout (as suggested in docs) I can successfully create BillingAgreement and recieve a token. Now after user follows a link like https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=[token goes here] , agrees to all terms and conditions etc., he is automatically redirected to returnUrl provided in SetExpressCheckout method, and additionally this token value is appended to the returnUrl.

So far so good. Now the question is - can I rely on the fact that returnUrl will be called at all times? F. e., what happens when for some reason user's browser refuses or fails to be redirected to the specified url?

As far as I can understand from PayPal documentation, you cannot use IPN to notify you of new subscriptions, initiated by user, though clearly IPNs would be an ideal option. I have tried to provide notifyUrl when I compose SetExpressCheckout request, but it is not being hit. Same IPN works fine for "pay" method which I use for one-time purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a step in there.  The recurring payments profile doesn't get created while the buyer is on the PayPal website -- you have to wait for the buyer to come back to your return URL, then call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile to actually create the recurring payment.  If you never call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, then no recurring payment gets created -- which is probably why you're not getting any IPNs.

Comment: Yep, I know I have to call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile once user has agreed to create billing agreement. Question is - when is the right time for me to call it. If there is a quarantee that user will actually be redirected to the returnUrl, then it is fine and I can work with this. Btw propably it is even better to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails once returnUrl is hit to check with paypal servers if this is a valid request by real paypal user.

Comment: The right time to call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile is after the buyer hits the returnUrl.  PayPal redirects the buyer to the returnUrl as soon as they click the "Agree and Continue" button on PayPal, so the fact that they're hitting your returnUrl means that they've agreed to the purchase/recurring payment.  It's not 100% guaranteed that the buyer will hit your returnUrl -- because network outages can occur, or the buyer could decide to cancel the payment -- but the chances are close to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I guess this is as close to a guarantee as I can get from PayPal. I supposed this was the only way, but wanted to make sure. Too bad there is no way to recieve IPN notifications from PayPal on new subscriptions request, but it is manageable.